# Security within SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016, reportmanager

I have created an ssrs report that displays through the report manager and shows rows attached to users. Basically each row is a different user. What I need to do is only show the rows that belong to the user who is running the report.

I know there is a relatively simple way to do this within the stored procedure but that was a long time ago and I cannot find my example. Any ideas?

Comment: rows from what?

Comment: add a where clause to the query would do it. If you would show us some code we could help you with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a field containing `User!UserID` which will give you the user id running the report.

You can conditionally show/hide sections & rows by right-clicking on the row/section header on the left side of the design screen and adding a condition for making the row visible when a field from your query matches User!UserID.

Comment: Thanks Terry, exactly what I was after!!

Comment: Always happy to help!